# Prove that $\sin^{2}{\theta} + \cos^{2}{\theta} = 1.$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

I believe that I have been able to prove that Prove $\sin^{2}{\theta} + \cos^{2}{\theta} = 1, \forall \theta,$ but I would like to ask if my proof is correct / valid.

[image]

Comment: it seems correct to me.

Comment: What if $\theta$ is outside the interval $0 \le \theta < \pi/2$?

Comment: This is not a proof, but instead a restatement of the Pythagorean Theorem. An easier way to proceed from the PT is to divide both sides by $c^2.$

Answer (score 3):

The direction is correct in general. But I recommend skipping the step in 2nd equation, $B=\frac A{\tan\theta}$, as when $\theta=0,\tan\theta=0$ and $B$ is not defined. It'd be better if you directly write $B=C\cos\theta$, in which $B$ is well-defined for all $\theta$.

Btw, have you also considered the case beyond $0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}2$?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $\theta$ to be any radians, then you have to define $\cos \theta, \sin \theta$ as the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point that is on the unit circle $r = 1$ and also on the terminal side of the angle $\theta$ radians in standard position, then by Pythagorean theorem you have: $x^2+y^2 = 1$, proving your formula.